# Second derivate of parametric equations (Intuitive)

Tags: calculus, derivatives, parametric, parametrization

let:
$$x=f(t)$$
$$y=g(t)$$
hence:
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy/dt}{dx/dt} $$

How can I derive the formula for the second derivative of a parametric equation?

Comment: Hint:
$$
\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2} = \frac{d}{dx} \left( \frac{dy}{dx} \right)
$$

Comment: @PrincessEev more hints, please

Comment: If $y'_x=\frac{y'_t}{x'_t}$, then $y''_{x^2}$ will be derivative of fraction i.e. ... Can you finish?

Comment: quotient rule?.

Comment: there is a catch thought because the why in the numerator we have y'' and denomianor just x'

Comment: Remember If $y'_x=\frac{y'_t}{x'_t}$, then $y'_x=y'_t\cdot t'_x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $y'_x=\frac{y'_t}{x'_t}$, then $y'_x=y'_t\cdot t'_x$. Using this for second derivative gives
$$y''_{x^2} = (y'_x)'_x=\left( \frac{y'_t}{x'_t} \right)_t\cdot t'_x\quad(1)$$

$y''_{x^2}$ will be derivative of fraction i.e.
$$y''_{x^2}=\frac{\frac{dx}{dt}\cdot\frac{d^2y}{dt^2} - \frac{d^2x}{dt^2}\cdot\frac{dy}{dt}}{\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2}\cdot \frac{dt}{dx}=\\=\frac{x'_ty''_{tt}-y'_tx''_{tt}}{x'^3_t}\quad(2)$$

Comment: the answer should be $$\frac{dy'/dt}{dx/dt}$$

Comment: me bad for the lack  of details

Comment: Don't understand $y'$ in your comment in $\frac{dy'/dt}{dx/dt}$. Is it for $y'_x$? In question you have correct formula.

Comment: $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac{dy'/dt}{dx/dt}$$ would like to see the derivation of that one. my comments are wrong

Comment: look at  formula $(1)$ in my answer.

Comment: by $$t'_x = \frac{dx}{dt}$$?

Comment: because: $$dy/dt = dy/dx * dx/dt$$

Comment: Yes. Last both are correct.